# Doing Postback but returning to same position on Form

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep page position on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692223/keep-page-position-on-postback)

How do you return to the same position on a form after doing a postback?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need [**MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)

```
  <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

If you want it throughout website

```
use Web.config page section <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: This won't work cross-browser...

Answer (score 2):

Set the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` to `True` in page directives.