# WinJs Navigating Back At Same Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm working on Windows 8 Store Application ( with WinJS - html5,js,jquery ) and I'm trying to use that;

```
WinJS.Navigation.back();
```

This back function working and it returns one page back. But I want to return the page's position where I was there...

I mean; First page:

A B C D E

```
   ^ I scrolled to right and clicked item on C position
```

At the new page: I clicked back button ( which calls "WinJs.Navigation.back()" )

And currently, Navigator moved me to the head of the page which is position "A".

So this is the problem. I want to return "C" point.

I don't want to use custom-tagging style, like ; >[here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/114166/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Return-position-page-post)<

I think there should be default function to do that, like ; > [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673876/doing-postback-but-returning-to-same-position-on-form) <

Answer (score 2):

You need to store that scroll position somewhere - probably in the navigation stack - and restore it when you get the navigated event from the navigation service that says your page has been (re)presented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListView object, use the indexOfFirstVisible method as it "scrolls so that the item with the specified index is the first visible item" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700691.aspx